# QuickBooks (Mac) Chart of Accounts has an empty column with a blue ball heading

Tags: macos, mac, quickbooks, accounting

QuickBooks 2014 (Mac)

I'm simply looking for an explanation of an empty column in my Chart of Accounts.  Its header is nothing but a blue ball.  Hovering and clicking this column heading reveals nothing.  Googling leads nowhere except extreme frustration.

Please explain what this empty column is supposed to represent.  Thank-you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Intuit user forum, this column would indicate which account(s) are setup for online banking.

IMO, a good GUI would *automatically* hide this column when no accounts are setup with online banking, or at the very least, show a tooltip when hovering over the heading.

**EDIT**:  After activating the "guide me" function, and waiting a bit of time, a tooltip eventually shows up and explains this column.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to remove the empty column.